# DNS or something else? I can't access my website when I add www. infront of it

Tags: domain-name-system, web

I run a fresh Linux Mint 18 install, Apache2 web server hosted by me. I can access the website by IP, http://domain.tld however when I try http://www.domain.tld I get no response. My single and only DNS configuration is [Type] A record [Host] @ [Value] X.X.X.X [TTL] Auto.

I never modified any file or config after installing Apache2. Did I miss something? What am I doing wrong?

I've been looking for 2 days all around the net and I can't find out what is it.

Comment: have you tried the super simple task of using `dig www.domain.eu` to see if there if the address can be resolved?  based on what you have described you need an additional record(CNAME can be used).  Do some Googling for "www CNAME record" and try to find a result from your hosting provider.

Comment: Next time you have a DNS problem, post your zone. Or give us your real domain name. It would really help a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To confirm if you have a DNS problem simply open NSLOOKUP from a command prompt. Enter your domain name without www and then again with www and compare ip address and make sure they match.

[image]

Comment: I checked and the IP does not match. the non www uses my IP, the other uses some other random IP.

Comment: Thats your problem then.  Who hosts your DNS for domain name? If you are unsure, open nslookup and type: set type=ns then enter your domain name that should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Namecheap, I've already contacted them, thank you very much guys for your help I wouldn't had find out the problem otherwise.